# groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder not working in jenkins

Tags: xml, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to create a new Xml file and add already parsed data from other file to it using groovy

But jenkins is throwing a error stating "No such property settings for class StreamingMarkupbuilder "

settingsObj is already parsed data which I am trying to add to this file

```
def xmlFile=new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{
    settings{
        mkp.yeild settingsObj.servers.children()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to move builder code into a function and mark it `@NonCPS`